# Is the a way to download a file to ftp from chrome?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

Is there a way to download files while browsing in chrome to my ftp server without opening another application or program or downloading it onto my computer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CurlFTPFs` to mount your FTP server in a local directory where you can then download files via any download manager including Chrome's built-in one. The files will be uploaded automatically and transparently.

CurlFtpFS is a filesystem for accessing FTP hosts based on FUSE and libcurl

First you'll need to install CurlFTPs
`sudo aptitude install curlftpfs`

Edit your fstab
`gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`
and add the following line:

```
curlftpfs#ftpUsername:ftpPassword@ftp://ftpUrl /localDirectory fuse rw,uid=1000,umask=0777,user,suid,allow_other,exec,auto,utf8  0   1
```

Save and exit then run `mount -a`

You'll need to edit `/etc/rc.local` to make it run properly at boot. Add the following before the `exit 0` line:

```
sudo curlftpfs -o umask=0777,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other ftp://username:password@your.ftpserver.here /localdirectory
```

Comment: the Q says _download files to ftp server (directory)_...